# How can I fix the TableViewCell position unchanged?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to make the positions of the last three TableViewCells in the second Section always be fixed at the end, without being affected by the drag and drop of other Cells? I just want to make the position of the last three cells fixed.
[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ywqX.png)

Comment: I think you want to use these cells in `tableView`'s `footerView`. please search about tableView footerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath"!

Answer (score 0):

if last one should not be affected by other part scrolling you should put them in another bottomTableView. If last 3 are not should be cells, you can use tableview.footerView and put there you static bottom part

Comment: Thank you. I will try it right away. I only thought of footerView before, and forgot to try to use two tableviews.

Comment: I still don't understand how to put these cells in a bottomTableView.